# Ansible lineinfile replace line after regex

Tags: regex, ansible

I have a file with a lot different entrys. It looks like this:

> ```
>        -  file:
>             url: filestore://20180205/group2/test123.xml
>             sha1: b856565abe4d9416323d82fce9005db29e9a6c57
>           dest_folder: group-2
>           ensure: present
>        -  file:
>             url: filestore://20180213/group2/othertest.xml
>             sha1: ec9d3d82232c05f7b49a034dcec9ea83f5c1981a
>           dest_folder: group-2
>           ensure: present
> ```

Now I need to change the url and the sha1 line with new data.
The url line I can change with the lineinfile module, because I know the group and the name of the file, but I don't know the sha1 value.

So how can I change the sha1 line?

I tried it like this:

```
---
- name: regex Test
  hosts: localhost
  become: no
  tasks:
    - name: regex two lines
      lineinfile:
        dest: /tmp/testdatei
        regexp: 'group2/test123.xml'
        line: '                url: filestore://gpv/hal/20180213/group2/test1'

    - name: regex two lines
      lineinfile:
        dest: /tmp/testdatei
        regexp: 'group2/test123.xml
                sha1: '
        line: '                sha1: test'
```

Ansible add the new sha1 line at the end of file and don't replace it with the current sha1 line.

Answer (score 0):

**Use ansible [replace module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/replace_module.html)**

```
- name: regex two lines
  replace:
    dest: /tmp/testdatei
    regexp: '^(\s*url: ).*group2/test123.xml\n(\s*sha1: ).*$'
    replace: '\1filestore://gpv/hal/20180213/group2/test1\n\2test'
    backup: yes
```

Comment: Thank you. I have fount the replace modul and used it, but in a bit a different way :)

Answer (score 0):

I have found now a solution.

```
---
- name: replace url and hash
  replace:
    path: /tmp/testdatei
    regexp: 'test1\n[^\n]+'
    replace: 'FileName\nsha1hash'

- name: regex url
  lineinfile:
    dest: /tmp/testdatei
    regexp: 'FileName'
    line: '                url: filestore://gpv/hal/{{current_date}}/{{group_name}}/{{file_name}}'

- name: regex hash
  lineinfile:
    dest: /tmp/testdatei
    regexp: 'sha1hash'
    line: '                sha1: {{sha1var.stdout}}'
```

I made it like this, because the must be correctly the same.